# Poor disk performance with ASUS EEE BOX

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, performance

I have an ASUS EEE BOX and I am experiencing really poor disk performance.

How can I debug and fix it?

Answer (score 1):

After doing a bit of googling for you, it looks like some of the early EEE Box machines only have a laptop 4200RPM Drive, when you compare this to a desktop 7200 RPM, it is simply very slow under loads.

If you have a later mode, you will most likly have a 5400RPM drive which is faster, but still no match.

You can try downloading a tool such as Process Explorer or Process Monitor and selecting a column that will allow you to see what programs are doing the most read/write operations and then you can close them, however this does not make up for getting a faster hard drive.

UTILITIES -

Process Explorer - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx
Process Monitor - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, there's not much you can do: the disk has slow rotational speed.

By the way, if you hear clicking in Windows, be sure to install [quietHDD](http://sites.google.com/site/quiethdd/).

My plan, when buying the EEE, was to subject myself to the somewhat reduced speed, and when SSDs become cheap, throw a big and fast one in there. Still seems like a good plan.